Dependent is insured through COBRA, when they turn 26 can they elect COBRA again?
I was on my dad's insurance. When he retired in 2020, he went on Medicare, and enrolled me and my siblings in COBRA. I am about to turn 26. I know that "dependents may enroll in COBRA for up to 36 months if the dependent child marries or reaches age 26", but my question is can I enroll in COBRA again?
In my experience the former employer sends a COBRA election notice, who would send that in this case, the insurance company?

Are you on COBRA since 2020? Hasn't it been more than 36 months already?


In my experience the former employer sends a COBRA election notice,
who would send that in this case, the insurance company?

When you lose coverage you have the option regarding getting coverage:

Your employer
The affordable care act
Your current coverage via COBRA.

You pick based on cost, your doctors, your coverage. Generally COBRA coverage is the most expensive, because you don't get help from your employer, or a tax credit that may be available from the ACA coverage. But you have to do the math.
If a person is 26 and unemployed (or doesn't qualify for insurance from their employer), but was on their parents coverage, they can pick COBRA or ACA when they turn 26.
If you have coverage via the ACA or your employer already there is nothing special about turning 26.

When you say "your current coverage via COBRA" is this something I would have to re-elect?

When you lost the coverage you were sent the paperwork to continue the coverage, if you didn't signup by the deadline the option was lost.
